# PageIndexChanging which wasn't handled

Tags: c#, .net, page-index-changed

I have set up EnableSortingAndPagingCallbacks="True" for a gridview and I don't have any template columns.

Paging works fine on all browsers without any errors but only few users ( not all IE8 users) of IE8 reported PageIndexChanging which wasn't handled error. Is it option settings issue on their browsers?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try to set `OnPageIndexChanging` event handler of your grid view like this

```
protected void gridView_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
   gridView.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
   gridView.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: No I shouldn't need to handle this event coz  EnableSortingAndPagingCallbacks="True" shouldn't postback a page and that's how it works fine with most of the browsers,only few users of IE 8 reported the error.

Comment: @user228777 are you binding the gridview to a custom datasource?

Comment: As I mentioned earlier everything is working fine on IE9 , IE8 and other browsers, only few users reported above error on IE 8, so it must be internet option settings??

Comment: I already saw that forum but not sure about the solution since it works fine on 98% of my users other than few IE8 uers